# C# Client video streaming application can't capture stream

Tags: c#, wpf, video-streaming, clr, mediaelement

I 'm working on a video streaming client-server application. Server is a unix application that streams video via ffmpeg (*.swf* stream). I want client to be a Windows application, but I found difficulties of how I must implement it.

I 'm thinking of implementing it in c#, in a Windows Forms application (VS 2012) making use of *VLC ActiveX Plugin* or *WMP*. However, I didn't find any related implementation and I don't know much about how to start.

I also tried implementing the client on a WPF application, using MediaElement. For this reason, I added on MediaElement the following code:

```
<Grid>
      <MediaElement Name="VideoControl" Source="http://server_ip_address:port" />
</Grid>
```

but I didn't catch any video stream.

I 'm a bit confused about which implementation I should follow about the client and any help or relative reference to study would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to open this stream using the Windows Media Player then you can use WPF MediaElement (it uses same WMP ActiveX). Otherwise try to open it using the VLC Playe and then you can try to use for example [nVLC library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC).

Btw. there are also some commercial products like [Streamcoders](http://streamcoders.com/) or [Leadtools](http://www.leadtools.com/)